# PYTHONPATH variable can't be echoed by non-root

Tags: linux, python, path, sudoers, fedora-21

I edited my sudoers file by getting root privilege as `sudo -i`

Then I edited my sudoers file by `nano /etc/sudoers`

I added `Defaults    env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to the sudoers file.

Then from **root**, I echoed `PYTHONPATH` as  `echo $PYTHONPATH` and it echoed successfully.

But when I exit from root and then echo `PYTHONPATH` it displays nothing.

Is there any solution to this problem?
Kindly help me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you set PYTHONPATH in a root shell then exited that shell and expected PYTHONPATH to persist. This isn't possible as environment variables can only be set by a process before starting a child process, a child cannot change its parent's environment.

Comment: So, then how can I change the PYTHONPATH system variable??

Comment: On Fedora, you should create a file in `/etc/profile.d` containing `export PYTHONPATH=...`.

Comment: But be careful, because a lot of system utilities use Python, and altering `PYTHONPATH` risks breaking that. It's probably better to accomplish this in a different way.

Comment: What are you trying to do?